# SUBSTRING_INDEX Not Warking in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find max invoice:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice,'I', -1)) + 1, 1) AS invoice
FROM sales
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e779be/1)

When I run this SQL query, it can not count more than 10.

| invoice |
| --- |
| 20221026P1I1 |
| 20221026P1I2 |
| 20221026P1I3 |
| 20221026P1I4 |
| 20221026P1I5 |
| 20221026P1I6 |
| 20221026P1I7 |
| 20221026P1I8 |
| 20221026P1I9 |
| 20221026P1I10 |
| 20221026P1I11 |
| 20221026P1I12 |

I am trying to find max invoice 12 + 1 = 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is correct, however you should cast the string value to a bona fide integer:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice, 'I', -1) AS UNSIGNED)), 1) AS invoice
FROM sales;
```

The problem with trying to find the max of the text substrings themselves is that text numbers sort lexicographically, e.g.

```
1
10
11
2
23
```

But this isn't the behavior you want, you want the numeric maximum.  Hence we should cast these substrings and then compare.

Side note: You could have avoided this problem entirely by maintaining a pure numeric invoice number column.  You may want to change your table design to include such a column.